# Dynamics SolutionPackager.exe Value must not be null

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, add-in

I have a dynamics solution, which I want to pack using the SolutionPackager.exe from the dynamics SDK.
I am getting the error, that a value must not be null.
I am wondering what is expected in the Relationship.xml, if I do not want to change any entities. Any ideas on this?

After googling a while I only found argument null errors while using dynamics, like this: https://msdynamicsworld.com/story/resolving-error-value-cannot-be-null-issue-microsoft-dynamics-365-project-service-automation, but I cant get even close to that step.

```
PS D:\Source\github\D365-PowerKanban\src\web\Solutions\src> D:\Dynamics\SDK\Bin\SolutionPackager.exe /a:pack /z:D:\Source\github\D365-PowerKanban\package.zip /e:verbose
SolutionPackger : CRM Solution Packaging Tool [Version 8.2.0.820]
© 2012 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved


Packing D:\Source\github\D365-PowerKanban\src\web\Solutions\src to D:\Source\github\D365-PowerKanban\package.zip

Processing Component: Entities
Processing Component: Roles
Processing Component: Workflows
Processing Component: FieldSecurityProfiles
Processing Component: Templates
Processing Component: EntityMaps
Processing Component: EntityRelationships
Reading: .\Other\Relationships.xml
Processing Component: optionsets
Processing Component: SolutionPluginAssemblies

Unmanaged Pack complete.

Processing Component: Entities
Processing Component: Roles
Processing Component: Workflows
Processing Component: FieldSecurityProfiles
Processing Component: Templates
Processing Component: EntityMaps
Processing Component: EntityRelationships
Reading: .\Other\Relationships.xml
Processing Component: optionsets
Processing Component: SolutionPluginAssemblies
Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein.
Parametername: path
CrmSvcUtil Runtime = 00:00:00.1430334
```

Relationship.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EntityRelationships xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out, that I used the wrong version. Use this to solve the issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/download-tools-nuget?view=op-9-1